# Change image resource using attributes and themes

Tags: java, android, attributes, android-layout, themes

I can't figure out how to change image resource of ImageButton in code. I have defined following theme in themes.xml:

```
<resources>
   <style name="MMTheme.Blue">
        <item name="playButtonImg">@drawable/play_button</item>
        <item name="pauseButtonImg">@drawable/pause_button</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

Attributes are defined in attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="pauseButtonImg" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="playButtonImg" format="integer"/>
</resources>
```

Now I want to change the image resource of ImageButton. I can change it by:

```
playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);
```

But I want use themes. How to change it using the playByttonImg attribute so I can use different images for different themes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I have solution for the original question:

```
public static int getStyledDrawableId(Context context, int attribute)
{
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { attribute });
    int id = a.getResourceId(0, -1);
    return id;
}
```

It returns me a drawable id when I call for example: `getStyledDrawableId(getContext(), R.attr.playButtonImg)` . Context HAS TO have the selected theme set.

Attributes should be changed to reference format:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="pauseButtonImg" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="playButtonImg" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how to access the styles from themes programaticaly, so I had to use a trick with two separate buttons. Each has own style and instead of changing image/style of one button, I am setting the visibility of two styled buttons.